# In Autolayout, how to make NSWindow resize back to smallest size after removing custom view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autolayout

I'm using AutoLayout to make a NSWindow resize to the content's intrinsic size. This works quite well the first time I add a subview to the NSWindow's contentView and then add a visual constraint such as "H:|[view]|" and "V:|[view]|".

I later remove this view (removeFromSuperView) and add another view to the window and add the new constraints for the newly added view. However at this point the NSWindow does not shrink to take up the minimum size of the new view. It instead 'expands' the newly added view to reflect the old size of the Window.

I've set content hugging priority for the contentView to 1000 (horizontal and vertical) thinking that would work however nothing does. I've also tried calling invalidateIntrinsicContentSize on the newly added view as well as updateConstraints on the NSWindow but nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the following worked. I set 0 height and width @ 550 priority and it caused the window to 'hug' the content the way I wanted it to:

```
  [customView setAlphaValue:0];
  [customView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
  [self.window.contentView customView];

  NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(customView);

  [self.window.contentView addConstraints:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[customView(0@550)]|"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                             views:views]];

  [self.window.contentView addConstraints:
   [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[customView(0@550)]|"
                                           options:0
                                           metrics:nil
                                             views:views]];
```